# When do we use hidden induction?

Tags: soft-question, induction

If I'm correct, hidden induction is when we use something along the lines of "etc..." in a proof by induction. Are there any examples of when this would be appropriate (or when it's not appropriate but used anyway)?

Comment: +1 This is a good question that reflects healthy meta-level introspection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, "Hidden induction is when we use something along the lines of 'etc ...' in a proof by induction". So *hidden induction* occurs inside proofs by induction only?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's ubiquitous in inductive proofs by *telescopy*, e.g. multiplicative telescopic  cancellation

$\qquad\qquad\, \displaystyle (x-1)(x+1)(x^{\large 2}\!+1)(x^{\large 4}\!+1)\qquad\! \cdots\qquad (x^{\large 2^{\rm N}}\!+\,1)$

$\qquad\ \ \ = \ \displaystyle  \frac{\color{#0a0}{x-1}}{\color{#90f}1} \frac{\color{brown}{x^{\large 2}-1}}{\color{#0a0}{x-1}}\frac{\color{royalblue}{x^{\large 4}-1}}{\color{brown}{x^{\large 2}-1}}\frac{\phantom{f(3)}}{\color{royalblue}{x^{\large 4}-1}}\, \cdots\,  \frac{\color{#c00}{\large x^{\large 2^{\rm N}}\!-1}}{\phantom{f(b)}}\frac{x^{\large 2^{\large \rm N+1}}\!-1}{\color{#c00}{x^{\large \rm 2^N}\!-1}} \,=\,  \frac{x^{\large 2^{\rm N+1}}-1}{\color{#90f}1} $

As to your question about rigor, informal proofs like the above can be  *mechanically* rewritten into a rigorous inductive proof by anyone who is proficient with telescopic induction. But that is not necessarily the case for someone who is not (esp. for hairer problems where the telescopic cancellation is not so obvious).

Thus typically  it depends upon the context whether or not such informal proofs will be accepted as complete. If we are in a context where it is assumed that telescopic induction is known then such informal proofs may indeed be deemed acceptable. Otherwise more needs to be said to convince the reader that you know how to complete the proof into standard inductive form.

Similar remarks hold for other common forms of inductive proofs. For example, many of my posts illustrate how the use of modular arithmetic (congruences) allows us to transform many inductive divisibility problems into a trivial induction such as $\, x\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x^n\equiv 1,\,$ a consequence of the Congruence Power Rule (which has an *obvious* simple inductive proof). In a number theoretical context you would not be expected to give a rigorous inductive proof of the concluding inference, essentially $\,1^n\equiv 1\,$ (or, similarly $(-1)^{2n}\equiv 1).$ But in other contexts you would be expected to be more explicit, esp, if you are working without the simplifying language of congruences, so the innate algebraic structure may be much more obfuscated, greatly complicating the intuition needed to devise the inductive step. For example [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/695494/242) where I explain how a divisibility  inductive proof that is typically pulled out of a hat like magic, is nothing but a special case of the Congruence Product Rule, and the inductive proof becomes obvious from the algebraic perspective.

Comment: I've seen some pretty strange cases of telescoping stuff that are very much not obvious.  Though I've seen yours, and just for the heck of it, I took the log of it and posted it as a problem somewhere.

Comment: Even before the telescoping: as soon as we write the product or sum of an arbitrary finite series at all (whether as e.g. $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n}$ or as $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^n}$), we’re using something that’s defined by a hidden induction.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's why I wrote it using ellipses instead of product notation.   This is even more subtle, having to do with the role that induction plays in recursively defined functions - see the Henkin paper [linked here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143539/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque: sure, I just wanted to make the point that the hidden induction isn’t just in the proof of the telescoping but also even in the definition of the product.  I don’t think the notational difference (ellipsis vs. product notation) affects that, except insofar as the ellipsis version is more clearly slightly informal.

Comment: @Peter It does in the sense that if one is using the product notation then presumably that has already been rigorously defined.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example. Suppose that $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix, i.e. $A=P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is some diagonal matrix. Then $A^k=P^{-1}D^kP$. Indeed, we have that $$A^k=(P^{-1}DP)^k=P^{-1}D(PP^{-1})D(PP^{-1})\dots (PP^{-1})DP=P^{-1}D^kP.$$ Here we actually used induction in the dots. There are many examples of this fashion.

Comment: It's supposed to be $(PP^{-1})$ instead of $(P^{-1}P)$, right?

Comment: Yes, sloppy mistake.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

First, here is an example of when this works. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff spaces. This implies $X\times Y$ with the product topology is Hausdorff. Therefore any finite product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff. The "hidden induction" is the idea that $X\times Y$ is a Hausdorff space, which implies any Hausdorff space times $X\times Y$ is also Hausdorff. This argument can continue for any finite number of spaces.

An example of when you can't use this argument is the proof of $\Sigma_{i=1}^n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Here, showing the truth for $n=1$ does not make it immediately clear that the rest follows by induction.

It was appropriate to use this in the first problem as it was clear that it follows. But the second problem isn't as obvious. It is like a lot of other problems in mathematics; the mathematician must develop an intuition for when something is obvious enough to not require an explicit explanation (e.g. $2*1=2$).

Comment: For the first case, we have a pattern that doesn't rely on intuition: We have two objects that both have a property, and combine it to one object that also has this property. Therefore we can recursively combine finitely many such objects and the result will still have that property.

Answer (score 4):

Hidden induction happens a lot in cases where you go *backwards* from $n$ to $1$, using some kind of reduction argument. For example, the proof that every number can be written as a product of primes:

> Let $n$ be some number. If it's prime, then we're done. Otherwise it can be written as $ab$, with $a, b < n$. Again, if both $a$ or $b$ are prime, we're done, otherwise they can be broken up in the same way. Since the factors are getting smaller and smaller, this process must stop eventually, but the only way it can stop is if one of all of the numbers involved are prime.

Induction serves to tighten up the structure of the argument, replacing a vague "this process must stop" with an explicit invocation of an axiom:

> Suppose every number less than $n$ can be written as a product of primes. If $n$ is prime, we're done. Otherwise, $n=ab$ with $a, b < n$, so $a$ and $b$ can be written as products of primes. Therefore $n$ can be written as a product of primes.

Comment: I realize this is not what the questioner initially intended, but +1 for pointing out that the use of the well-ordering principle is another kind of "hidden" use of induction. I'd forgotten about that, which is surprising since I think about it fairly regularly.