# recursive sequence formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Find an explicit formula for the recursive sequence $a(n+1)=3a(n)-8$  where $a(1)=4$.

Is the formula  an=4 and how to prove it by induction I dont really know how to prove it using induction if this were the right answer

Comment: a(1)=4 .sorry i forgot to add it at the begining

Comment: No problem (+1) from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $a(n) = 4$. Given $a(1) = 4$ and $P(1)$ is true.

Assume $a(k) = 4$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. Then $$a(k+1) = 3a(k) - 8 = 12 - 8 = 4$$

So $P(k+1)$ is true.

Answer (score 6):

Hint (telescoping instead of induction): the recursion formula can be written as:

$$a_{n+1}-4=3(a_{n}-4)=3^2(a_{n-1}-4)=\cdots=3^{n}(a_1-4)$$

Comment: Hmmmm.  That part that reads "$\cdots$".  Isn't that shorthand for "induction"?

Comment: @GEdgar Telescoping is common enough that it has its own name, and is generally accepted without the formal base+step proof detail. Related: [When do we use hidden induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042428/when-do-we-use-hidden-induction)

Comment: @GEdgar It's how I write my induction all the time :P  (though I try to make it obvious)